# PHP insert into mysql cannot seem to get line breaks. I display in html the line breaks using . $var1 . PHP_EOL . inserts \r\n in the data

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, line-breaks

I cannot seem to get 4 lines of data to display in mysql description table as 4 separate lines when inserted. I get

```
AITS BARCODE: 80040602970001265369      MFG PN: 533-0017      MFG SN: C166089      QWERTY Keyboard ASSY, USB BACKLIT
```

instead of line breaks. If I use `\r\n` then that is directly inserted between the data (removes spaces, replaces with `\r\n`).

I created a test table and was able to insert 3 separate lines using

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (DESCR) VALUES (CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10 using utf8), '$mfgpn', '$mfgsn', '$descr'))";
```

But when I tried to do same to my table, it gave a '**using**' error in php error logs.

I display 4 separate lines using

```
<?php echo 'MFG PN: '. $mfgpn . '&#13;&#10;' . "MFG SN: " . $mfgsn . '&#13;&#10;'     . $descr; ?>
```

The separators does not put in `\r\n` like PHP_EOL does.

What is the proper way to take my data and insert 4 variables as 4 separate lines in my table? I have beat my brains out as this one is new to me.

Here is HTML presentation:

```
AITS BARCODE: 80040602970001265368
MFG PN: 130211
MFG SN: ST4315041285
Sensor Processor Card Module, (Sunhillo/Longport)
```

[image: textarea of html, 4 separate lines created]

Here is database result:

```
AITS BARCODE: 80040602970001265369      MFG PN: 533-0017      MFG SN: C166089      QWERTY Keyboard ASSY, USB BACKLIT
```

(no linebreaks, just whitespaces). Note. `PHP_EOL` for html line breaks causes `\r\n` to be inserted into database when double quoted. Note the html area is a textarea, if that matters. Records don't match but it's about presentation, not the data itself (data inserts fine, except I want it inserted exactly as seen on webpage).

Comment: If you look at the source in the browser, you may see the line breaks. The problem is that the browser does not process them as new lines, and ignores it. You need to convert newlines to `<br>` with [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) so that the line breaks will show on your page.

Comment: For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `it gave a 'using' error `...and what _exactly_ was the error? We can't help with errors if you don't clearly state them.

Comment: A line break in HTML is `<br/>` not `\r\n`. I can't work out why you are HTML-encoding `\r` and `\n` in that example.

Comment: Will you please stop breaking the formatting from the edits I've made? I'm trying to help you. I've rolled it back. Refresh your page if you can't see the changes.

Comment: The "HTML presentation" looks like it's actually inside a textarea, so yes `\r\n` would be fine as the line break there. Whether you see that when you look at it in the database may depend on whether the application you're using to view the results is a HTML-based application or not. You seem a bit confused about the difference between storage and display.

Comment: The 'using' error is when I used (CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10 using utf8) to insert 4 lines into a separate table. That worked. But when I tried to port it to my other table mysql was giving errors for 'using' in concat statement. If I insert \r\n into the table, the nl2br does nothing to render line breaks when pulling data back to browser. It shows the \r\n literally. If I replace the characters with <br /> then I get two breaks literally as html, not as html breaks.

Comment: `mysql was giving errors for 'using' in concat statement`...again, if you want help with that then please tell us the **exact** error message, and show the exact code which caused it.

Comment: `It shows the \r\n literally`... `then I get two breaks literally as html`...according to your screenshot, you're showing the data inside a textarea. This renders your text literally. HTML does not get rendered inside the textarea

Comment: Okay, figured out what will work. Insert an html break in the data going in. Then, do a str_replace on the data coming back to display within a textarea. Replace the html break with a PHP_EOL and viola, the data is presented like the user saw when it was inserted.  Here is db entry: AITS BARCODE: 80040602970001265369<br />MFG PN: 533-0017<br />MFG SN: C166089<br />QWERTY Keyboard ASSY, USB BACKLIT . By using str_replace and substituting br with PHP_EOL, it comes back the way I want it presented.

Comment: Great. You should write that as an answer, not a comment, and show the exact code you used! Then people can find it in searches, and upvote it if it's useful for them

Comment: Using an html textarea form, I bring in variables to create the 4 separate lines of data using php_eol for line breaks. This works fine.

Comment: See my comment above. write an answer! You'll get my upvote, at minimum :-). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I used php_eol for line breaks when inserting into database. When pulling it back you need to do  a str_replace to convert the hidden breaks in database to php_eol in the textarea you are bringing it back into.

`$newdescr = (str_replace('<br />', PHP_EOL, $mydescr));`

The problem I was having when I used php_eol is that if I used

`$mysqli -> real_escape_string(trim( $_POST['item_description']));`

it would insert \r\n to database. So I had to use

`(trim( $_POST['item_description']));`

and then I got actual breaks in database.